# Does a divorced/widow(er)ed person under the age of 20 in Thailand retain sui juris?

Tags: marriage, minor, sui-juris

[In Thailand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(law)#Thailand), a minor (one who has not received *[sui juris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sui_iuris)*) is a person under the age of 20. An exception is made if the person is married - [which can happen](http://www.thailandlawonline.com/thai-family-and-marriage-law/page-4) when both parties are over the age of 17.

Say a person at the age of 18 marries. The marriage could be terminated, in the instance of divorce or the death of the other partner.

If this termination happens before the person's 20th birthday, do they retain *sui juris*?

Comment: My guess is that someone who is married has crossed a "threshhold" of sui juris, and will not revert; but this is just a guess.

Comment: @TomAu I agree: it would be completely insane otherwise, since you may have signed a contract and then you would not be allowed to modify it or sign other similar contracts. But completely insane laws do exist, so, deeply sadly, this is a very valid question.

Answer (score 5):

They retain sui juris after "divorce" or death of a spouse.

A minor becomes sui juris upon marriage (civil marriage pursuant to Thai Civil and Commercial Code, article 1448). [Art. 20]  The status of sui juris won't be revoked by divorce or death.  This rule is not written in statutes but is interpreted in such manner.

However, if a court judged that marriage is null and void (e.g. a valid marriage did not exist because of same-sex marriage, polygamy, consanguineous marriage etc.) and a spouse is aged under 20, his/her status of sui juris also become null and void.